# Difference in methods of indexing multiple documents with Nest

Tags: nest

Using the 1.1.2 version of Nest, it seems there are at least 3 ways to index multiple documents:

### IndexMany

```
client.IndexMany(documents, "index_name", "type_name");
```

### Bulk with a BulkRequest parameter

```
client.Bulk(new BulkRequest(){
        Index = "index_name",
        Type = "type_name",
        Operations = documents_as_list_of_BulkIndexOperation
    });
```

### Bulk with a selector

```
client.Bulk(s => s.IndexMany(documents,
                             (bulkDescriptor, record) =>
                               bulkDescriptor.Index("index_name").Type("type_name)));
```

If I want to perform the same operation on all the documents (i.e. I don't want to take advantage of the Bulk API's ability to perform a different operation for each document as detailed in the docs), is there any advantage to calling `client.Bulk` over `client.IndexMany`?

Answer (score 6):

`IndexMany()` uses the `BulkIndexDescriptor` in it's implementation, so if you are only using `Bulk()` for indexing, then the two are functionally equivalent.  `IndexMany()` is just a shorthand alternative to using `Bulk`, simply added for convenience.